# SectionIndexTitles for a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uicollectionview

So I implemented a proper `TableView` with a search functionality and `sectionIndexTitles`. Now, I am trying to implement a `UICollectionView` and it is working so far, except that I can't easily have `sectionIndexTitles` (the right scroll bar).

If I look at the Facebook Application, it looks like a `UICollectionView`, but with indeed `sectionIndexTitles` and a searchbar. I can't seem to find such functions for the `UICollectionView` model.

Any ideas?!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'd like a good answer on this, too; I'd also like to avoid having another table view hidden, if possible (memory issues).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a similar requirement (for a horizontal collection view) and ended up building an index view subclass myself.

I plan to open-source it but that will likely have to wait until next month, so here's a stub to get you started:

**YMCollectionIndexView.h**

```
@interface YMCollectionIndexView : UIControl

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame indexTitles:(NSArray *)indexTitles;

// Model
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *indexTitles; // NSString
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSUInteger currentIndex;
- (NSString *)currentIndexTitle;

@end
```

**YMCollectionIndexView.m**

```
#import "YMCollectionIndexView.h"

@interface YMCollectionIndexView ()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSUInteger currentIndex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *indexLabels;
@end

@implementation YMCollectionIndexView

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame indexTitles:(NSArray *)indexTitles {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.indexTitles = indexTitles;
        self.currentIndex = 0;
        // add pan recognizer
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setIndexTitles:(NSArray *)indexTitles {
    if (_indexTitles == indexTitles) return;
    _indexTitles = indexTitles;
    [self.indexLabels makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self buildIndexLabels];
}

- (NSString *)currentIndexTitle {
    return self.indexTitles[self.currentIndex];
}

#pragma mark - Subviews

- (void) buildIndexLabels {
    CGFloat cumulativeItemWidth = 0.0; // or height in your (vertical) case
    for (NSString *indexTitle in self.indexTitles) {
            // build and add label
        // add tap recognizer
    }
    self.indexLabels = indexLabels;
}

#pragma mark - Gestures

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSString *indexTitle = ((UILabel *)recognizer.view).text;
    self.currentIndex = [self.indexTitles indexOfObject:indexTitle];
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

// similarly for pan recognizer

@end
```

**In your view controller:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionIndexView addTarget:self action:@selector(indexWasTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // similarly for pan recognizer
}

- (void)indexWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.collectionView scrollToIndexPath:...];
}

// similarly for pan recognizer
```

Comment: This looks awesome! If you open-source this, the iOS community at large will love you for it, I'm sure. Bounty awarded!

Comment: I've whipped up a full implementation (with writeup) in [a gist right here](https://gist.github.com/kreeger/4756030) — let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks like @BenKreeger created a GitHub repo/cocoapod for his solution: https://github.com/kreeger/BDKCollectionIndexView

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 14 (which has severely enhanced `UICollectionView`, in particular for making `UITableView` obsolete), this works as expected by implementing the delegate method `indexTitles`.

Answer (score 2):

The index titles do indeed work on iOS but it seems to only work on iOS 14+ when I tested.

```
func indexTitles(for collectionView: UICollectionView) -> [String]? {
    return Array(Set(objects.map{ String($0.name.prefix(1)) })).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPathForIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> IndexPath {
    guard let index = objects.firstIndex(where: { $0.name.prefix(1) == title }) else {
        return IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    }
    return IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: **This is verified to be fixed and works as intended now in iOS 14**

You can now simply use (as of iOS 10.3)

`optional func indexTitles(for collectionView: UICollectionView) -> [String]?`

Which expects an array like:
`['A', 'B' ,'C']`
as its return value.

Comment: this work for anyone? even in a simple example it I can't get the indexTitles func to get called.

Comment: Also keen on understanding how to use this new data source method. I have tried both on iOS 10.3 and tvOS 10.2 (as mentioned in the docs) but never got index titles showing up.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on iOS either (didn't try tvOS yet). The online documentation states it's available on iOS 10.3+ and tvOS 10.2+, but looking at the header files, it only says API_AVAILABLE(tvos(10.2)).

Comment: I poked around this for quite a while as well, with zero success.  I believe it is just not implemented.   I also searched for source code anywhere in the world :) that uses this feature and found none.

Comment: I posted a question on Apple Developer Forums https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95644

Comment: Unfortunately this is only implemented in tvOS, despite the online documentation stating otherwise. I've filed a radar for this.

Comment: I just got this working simply by adding it to my data source.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide this header by implementing and returning a value for the following function for [UICollectionViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012175)

```
collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

Note that the size of the header will be from the height value of the CGRect returned from [UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:

Comment: The question refers to the `sectionIndexTitles` on the right side of the screen, and not the supplementary section headers.