# iOS alphabetical scroll for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view which shows multiple images of peoples and their names, and I have implemented search and sorting functionality. However, the problem is I want alphabetical also, but the collection view does not have delegate methods like `UITableView` has.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"e", @"i", @"m", @"p", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString
    *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
        return <yourSectionIndexForTheSectionForSectionIndexTitle >;
}
```

I had tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882052/sectionindextitles-for-a-uicollectionview) also, but this shows collection view cells in a section. I don't want multiple sections. I want only section and implement alphabetical scroll functionality it.

Above methods are not in `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: Try to use a sort selector. This question might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically

Comment: i dont want to sort , as i mentioned ; i already impleneted sort functionality

Comment: possible duplicate of [SectionIndexTitles for a UICollectionView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882052/sectionindextitles-for-a-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 1):

[`BDKCollectionIndexView`](https://github.com/kreeger/BDKCollectionIndexView) implements a `UITableView`-like section index bar.  It's pretty easy to integrate once you have it positioned onscreen: just assign an array of `NSString`s from your datasource:

```
self.indexView.indexTitles = self.fetchResultsController.sectionIndexTitles;
```