# Alphabet Scroll in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview

I searched about this question here but I can't find anything useful related with my question. More similar is [IOS alphabetical scroll for uicollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365701/ios-alphabetical-scroll-for-uicollectionview) but is not solved. If anyone could guide me should be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing, I tried with sections but don't low how to add the alphabet scroll at right position.

Comment: check out this link.It may help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882052/sectionindextitles-for-a-uicollectionview