# Swift 3: How to make fast search in UICollectionView

Tags: performance, search, uicollectionview

In the contact App there is a row of letters in the right side where you can get fast to a point in the list.

I would like to do the same in my UICollectionView.

I did search for it, but without any luck so far.

So does anybody know how to adds those letters and use them in an UICollectionView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SectionIndexTitles for a UICollectionView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882052/sectionindextitles-for-a-uicollectionview)

Comment: That did not work for me. I'm also using Swift and not Object-C.

Comment: Has anybody else an answer for Swift?